# Sorting a deck of cards with Bogosort

Tags: probability, permutations, sorting

Suppose you have a standard deck of 52 cards which you would like to sort in a particular order. The notorious algorithm *Bogosort* works like this:

1. Shuffle the deck
2. Check if the deck is sorted. If it's not sorted, goto 1. If it's sorted, you're done.

Let *B(n)* be the probability that Bogosort sorts the deck in *n* shuffles or less. *B(n)* is a monotonically increasing function which converges toward 1. What is the smallest value of *n* for which *B(n)* exceeds, say, 0.9?

If the question is computationally infeasible then feel free to reduce the number of cards in the deck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An estimate. The probability that Bogosort doesn't sort the deck in a particular shuffle is $1 - \frac{1}{52!}$, hence $1 - B(n) = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{52}! \right)^n$. Since

$$\left( 1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)^n \approx e^{-x}$$

for large $n$, the above is is approximately equal to $e^{- \frac{n}{52!} }$, hence $B(n) \approx 0.9$ when

$$- \frac{n}{52!} \approx \log 0.1 \approx -2.30.$$

This gives

$$n \approx 2.30 \cdot 52! \approx 2.30 \cdot \sqrt{106\pi} \left( \frac{52}{e} \right)^{52} \approx 1.87 \times 10^{68}$$

by [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). By comparison, the current age of the universe is about $4.33 \times 10^{17}$ seconds, or about $4.33 \times 10^{32}$ flops if your computer runs at $1$ petaflops.

Comment: Better go put the kettle on while I wait for this deck to get sorted then..

Comment: @Sputnik: It is time for some intelligent intervention.